# trace http packet with wireshark

Tags: http

If I open an static webpage (don't have object to be updated) How can I identify the last http packet? Is there any properties in tcp or http that shows the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is dynamic what options will affect on receiving packet?For example Ajax or some other things that causes packets flow to come in wireshark and dont see no stop on packet flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for http packets at either the capture or display level. Then just scroll to the last packet.

Comment: Can we answer this question based on tcp header?

Comment: Only in the very simplest case where the page contains no images or other externally loaded content, in which case you'll get a packet with the FIN flag near the end. Depending on the implementation of the server, you might find you get one packet with the PUSH flag near the end too.